# Trying to remove some strings in C#

Tags: c#

I'm trying to make this:

```
G0E1X.52Y-.48M3S6000
H1Z-.2M8
G1Z.005F20.
X-6.82F18.
Y-.04
X.56
G0Z.2
```

Look like this:

```
E2X.52Y-.48
G1Z.005F20.
X-6.82F18.
Y-.04
X.56
G0Z.2
```

For every other copy I make, the number after the 'E' will increase by 1 (E3, E4, E5, etc.) while the rest of the text will stay the same.

So far, I have this, which while it works, I'm wondering if there's a better way to do the above.

*NOTE: Preview.Text contains a lot more text. However, the string 'DynamicPart' contains only the example shown above after executing the code shown below.*

```
            string Part = Preview.Text;
            int PartStart = Preview.Text.IndexOf("M6");
            int PartFinish = Preview.Text.IndexOf("M6", PartStart + 1);
            int PartLength = PartFinish - PartStart;
            Part = Preview.Text.Substring(PartStart, PartLength);
            int PartToolInfo = Part.IndexOf("E1", 0);
            Part = Part.Remove(0, PartToolInfo + 2);
            int PartM1 = Part.IndexOf("M");
            int PartM2 = Part.IndexOf("M", PartM1 + 1);
            Part = Part.Remove(PartM1, PartM2 - PartM1 + 2);
            string DynamicPart = Part;

            for (int x = 2; x <= Convert.ToInt32(NumberOfParts.Text); x++)
            {
                DynamicPart = Part.Insert(0, "E" + x);
                Preview.Text = Preview.Text.Insert(PartFinish, DynamicPart);
                PartFinish = Preview.Text.IndexOf("M6", PartStart + 1);
            }
```

Comment: This is more of a [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) question. SO is for questions about things that *don't* work.

Comment: @itsme86 is correct that this is a question for [codereview.se], because you are looking for open-ended suggestions for improvement of code that already works. (Note, however, that "SO is for questions about things that don't work" is a statement that is not supported by Stack Overflow's [help/on-topic] page. Rather, this question is inappropriate for Stack Overflow because there is no _specific programming problem_ to be solved.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try something like this

```
using System;

public class RemoveTest {
public static void Main() {

    string name = "Michelle Violet Banks";

    Console.WriteLine("The entire name is '{0}'", name);

    // remove the middle name, identified by finding the spaces in the middle of the name...
    int foundS1 = name.IndexOf(" ");
    int foundS2 = name.IndexOf(" ", foundS1 + 1);

    if (foundS1 != foundS2 && foundS1 >= 0) {

        name = name.Remove(foundS1 + 1, foundS2 - foundS1);

        Console.WriteLine("After removing the middle name, we are left with '{0}'", name);
    }
  }
}
// The example displays the following output:
//       The entire name is 'Michelle Violet Banks'
//       After removing the middle name, we are left with 'Michelle Banks'
```